# Solidity / Oraclize API out of gas exception

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to test this code on `https://dapps.oraclize.it` and each time I try to run test function, I get error VM Exception: Out of gas. However in the editor I have provided gas limit like 50000000000.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract Ballot is usingOraclize {
    function test() {
        oraclize_query("URL", "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT");
    }    
}
```

Can someone help me...

Comment: Are you sending any `value` when you create the contract?

Comment: the oracle query function (test) must be marked as payable and you will need to have a callback function in the contract which would be called by the oracle. Also, don't forget to send some value(ether) along with the tx.

Answer (score 0):

the oracle query function (test) must be marked as payable and you will need to have a callback function in the contract which would be called by the oracle. Also, don't forget to send some value(ether) along with the tx.